Wildfly, Arquillian Remote: Unknown service name jmx
I am using Wildfly 26.
While trying to use wildfly-arquillian-container-remote:2.2.0.Final I faced the following error during deployment:
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jboss.remoting3.ServiceOpenException: Unknown service name jmx
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
@RunAsClient
public class NovaApiDeploymentIT {

  @Deployment
  public static WebArchive createCommentsDeployment() {
      return ShrinkWrap.create(ZipImporter.class, "my.war")
          .importFrom(new File("target/my.war"))
          .as(WebArchive.class);
  }
}


Changing use-management-endpoint to true solved the issue.
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.3">
    <expose-resolved-model/>
    <expose-expression-model/>
    <remoting-connector use-management-endpoint="true"/>
</subsystem>

